# Does the print() Function Count as a Standard Output and does input() Count as a Standard Input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, output

Last week, I signed up for a reverse-engineering coding competition. The rules stated **"All input and output to the program must be through the standard streams (stdin and stdout, respectively")."** Upon reading that, I looked up their official **practice** test and started writing my code. I encountered many roadblocks because I was unfamiliar with the sys.stdin.read and sys.stdout.write functions. Then last night while I was researching ways to make my code better, I stumbled upon a coding blog stating the input() function is in fact a form of stdin. I looked around even more on the internet and came across a separate blog from another company that said relatively the same thing. So... is this true? Is input() and print() a form of stdin and stdout I can use for my competition?

Comment: `input` will read from the standard input device, and `print` will (by default, you can change the behavior if you want) print to teh standard output device, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, actually the [print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function uses [sys.stdout](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout) as its write() method.

In the python documentation, you can find that the print function is defined by:

```
print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
```

which file argument must be an object with a write(string) method. If it is not present or None, sys.stdout will be used. So by default print uses sys.stdout.

Also for the input function, you can find this sentence in the documentation:

[stdin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdin) is used for all interactive input (including calls to input()).

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought no one would answer because I am new to this site! :D